# Creating a table based on a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({ 'id' : [1,2,3,4], 'text' : ['Sample1', 'Sample2', 'Sample3', 'Sample4'] })
data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    id     text                                                                                                          
0   1  Sample1                                                                                                         
1   2  Sample2                                                                                                          
2   3  Sample3                                                                                                          
3   4  Sample4
```

I have a dataframe created in a python program. I am using `psycopg2` to connect to a `Postgres database`. Is there any way I can directly create a table in postgres using this dataframe in python as a reference?

Comment: did you try [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)?

Comment: Yes I have. But I dont want to use SQLAlchemy engine to do this.